# I can't get a separation line in a tabular

Tags: tables

So I want to add a line to separate the cells of 'Criteria' and '1'.
I tried to replace {`*`} by {`*|`}, but that misplaced the | .
If I use {`l|`}, an error appears.

```
\begin{table}[h!]  
\centering  
\begin{tabular}{|ll|l|l|l|l|} \cline{3-6}  
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{4}{l|} {Alternatives} \\ 
\cline{3-6}  
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline  
\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Criteria}}} & 1 & & & & \\ 
\cline{2-6}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & 2 & & & & \\ \cline{2-6}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & 3 & & & & \\ \cline{2-6}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & 4 & & & & \\ \cline{2-6}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & 5 & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2):

Next time please provide a full MWE...Did you meant like this?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1.5cm,top=1cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]  
    \centering  
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|} 
        \cline{3-6}  
        \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{4}{l|} {Alternatives} \\ 
        \cline{3-6}  

        \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline 
        \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Criteria}}} & 1 & & & & \\ 
        \cline{2-6}

        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & 2 & & & & \\ \cline{2-6}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & 3 & & & & \\ \cline{2-6}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & 4 & & & & \\ \cline{2-6}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & 5 & & & & \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You forget a '|' in the tabular definition.

Comment: I'm sorry, i just started using latex. But thank you!